# Excel: adding multiple h:mm:ss cells

Tags: excel

I am attempting to add three cells which I have formatted as hh:mm:ss
and it is giving me incorrect sum as one of them is missing hh

```
          A         B         c
      01:01:01   :01:01    01:01:01   SUM(A,B,C)
```

is returning 2:02:02 when it should be 2:03:03
I have several cells missing the HH so it is throwing off all my formulas, any way I can force the 00:01:01, on a cell that is :01:01?

Comment: Are you implying that those are all text-that-looks-like-time? I see no other reason to skip values like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TIMEVALUE(RIGHT("00:00"&TEXT(A2:C2, "[hh]:mm:ss;@"), 8)))
```

The format mask used by the TEXT function (`hh:mm:ss;@`) converts real time values to text-that-looks-like-time and leaves values that are already text-that-looks-like-time unchanged. Leading zeroes and a colon are concatenated onto the result as a prefix and the right-most eight characters are parsed off with the RIGHT function. This should cover both `:00:00` and `:00` text values. This allows the TIMEVALUE function to process the resulting text to a true time value. The SUMPRODUCT wrapper produces cyclic calculation so that you don't have to sum three largely redundant formulas.

In the following sample image, note the default left alignment of B2 indicating text while A2 and C2 are right aligned indicating a true number, date or time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the values will always be contiguous as you show, you can try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--("00"&A1:C1))
```

Prepending `"00"` and the double unary will have no affect on the real time values, but will convert the "missing hour" value to a real time